# file_exists with reserved filenames bug

Tags: php, filenames, file-exists, reserved

Ok here's my code

```
        $ref = $_GET['ref'];
        if (file_exists('views/'.$ref.'.php')) {
            $this->prepare($ref);
        } 
        elseif (!file_exists('views/'.$ref.'.php')) {
        echo 'Page you are requesting doesn´t exist';
        }
```

I'm currently having issues if users try to do ?ref=con or ?ref=com1 etc, file_exists will always return true. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You could move to a Un*x server where this doesn't happen. There is likely also some registry patch to disable those old DOS compatibility device filenames. Or try one of those NT fs prefixes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @mario: you should make that an answer. I had no idea those were reserved filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because those files actually exist. I'd be more worried about the potential for abuse. You should filter your inputs.

Also the `elseif` is unnecessary. `else` would suffice just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Yea i do sanitize them. Those files don't exist i think its just a bug or something.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using: is_file http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php

Comment: Thanks, but what does a 'regular' file mean?